# xsl:comment not apply all child elements?

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-2.0

I want to make comment which para which is containing 'para 1' same as input along with the child elements.

INPUT:

```
<root>
    <section>
        <title>aaaa</title>
        <para>para 1 <i>italic</i></para>
    </section>
    <section>
        <title>aaaa</title>
        <para>para 2</para>
    </section>
</root>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="para[contains(. , 'para 1')]">
    <xsl:comment>
            <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:comment>
</xsl:template>
```

OUTPUT:

```
<section>
    <title>aaaa</title>
    <!--para 1 italic-->
</section>
```

Desired output all elements should be copied as it is as input inside comment:

```
<section>
    <title>aaaa</title>
    <!--<para>para 1 <i>italic</i></para>-->
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can handle this with disable-output-escaping

```
 <xsl:template match="para[contains(. , 'para 1')]">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!--</xsl:text>
        <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">--&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="comment()[parent::para[contains(. , 'para 1')]]">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!- -</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">- -&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks @Rupesh. I did this way but i face one new scenario 'comment' already inside para in input. [i.e.  <para>para 1 <i>italic</i> <!-- aa --> </para>]. Then it is not producing well-form XML.

Comment: @Amrendra, Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to serialize the `para` element, then you can put its markup into a comment. Serialization is supported in XSLT 3/XPath 3 using Saxon 9.8 any edition or Altova 2017 R3 or 2018 using the `serialize` function:

```
<xsl:template match="para[contains(. , 'para 1')]">
    <xsl:comment select="serialize(.)"/>        
</xsl:template>
```

that way an input like

```
<root>
    <section>
        <title>aaaa</title>
        <para>para 1 <i>italic</i></para>
    </section>
    <section>
        <title>aaaa</title>
        <para>para 2</para>
    </section>
    <section>
        <para>para 1 <i>italic</i> <!-- aa --> </para>
    </section>
</root>
```

is transformed 9.8 into

```
<root>
        <section>
                <title>aaaa</title>
                <!--<para>para 1 <i>italic</i></para>-->
        </section>
        <section>
                <title>aaaa</title>
                <para>para 2</para>
        </section>
        <section>
                <!--<para>para 1 <i>italic</i> <!- - aa - -> </para>-->
        </section>
</root>
```

so contrary to the disable-output-escaping approach this will try to give you a result that is well-formed. I am not sure currently however how to get a format that would be reparseable.